# Random.sample with size of returned list being random also?

Tags: python

When using the `random.sample(sequence, k)`, how do you make the sample size `k` random?

example:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

random.sample(mylist, 2)
```

This would return two random numbers from my list. How do I make the the number of items returned random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass results of functions as parameters:

```
rand_size = random.randint(0, len(mylist))
random.sample(mylist, rand_size)
```

You can even do it in one line:

```
random.sample(mylist, random.randint(0, len(mylist)))
```

(You might want `random.randint(1, len(mylist))` instead, to avoid generating empty list)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
num = random.randint(0, len(mylist))
random.sample(mylist, num)
```

All this does is it uses `random` to generate a random number, between `0`, and the length of your list, then uses that as your sample num. You can put this in a function like this:

```
def rand_sample(mu_list):
    num = random.randint(0, len(mylist))
    random.sample(mylist, num)
```

Note that this can generate an empty list. If you don't want that, modify this line:

```
num = random.randint(0, len(mylist))
```

to

```
num = random.randint(1, len(mylist))
```

This just starts the random number from `1` to the length of the given list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> random.sample(mylist, random.randint(1,len(mylist)))
[4, 5, 1]
>>> random.sample(mylist, random.randint(1,len(mylist)))
[1]
```

just provide random values for k